# How to display value using Object Key and value in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I am new to ReactJS. I used context API to get the data. In my one of the states, I have Object inside Objects.

For Example:-

```
homeTeamClone: {
  "3a21b0a-1223-46-5abe-67b653be5704": {"id":"3a21b0a-1223-46-5abe-67b653be5704","memberName":"Adam"},
  "3a21b0a-1223-46-5abe-67b653be5705": {"id":"3a21b0a-1223-46-5abe-67b653be5705","memberName":"Chris"},
  "3a21b0a-1223-46-5abe-67b653be5706": {"id":"3a21b0a-1223-46-5abe-67b653be5706","memberName":"Martin"},
}
```

In another state I hold only keys for reference.

```
selectedMembers: {
"awayMember":"3a21b0a-1223-46-5abe-67b653be5704", "homeMember":"3a21b0a-1223-46-5abe-67b653be5705"}
```

Now in component when I tried to display like `<div>{homeTeamClone["3a21b0a-1223-46-5abe-67b653be5704"]}</div>` I'm getting an error asking I need to iterate to display the values or use array instead. But I don't want to use array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which property of the object `homeTeamClone["3a21b0a-1223-46-5abe-67b653be5704"]` to use want display? Try `homeTeamClone["3a21b0a-1223-46-5abe-67b653be5704"].memberName`.

Comment: I edited my question. I tried that but it is giving me same error. I can not use `<div>homeTeamClone[selectedMembers.awayMember]</div>`